# how to achieve Flutter WebView Scale to Fit

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve something like this in flutter webview.
[image]

but getting something like this.
[image]

how Can I achieve that first image kind of webview which will scale down the page.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set useWidePortView to true.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WebviewScaffold(
   initialChild: Loading(),
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text(title),
   ),
   url: url,
   withZoom: true,
   scrollBar: true,
   withJavascript: true,
   useWideViewPort: true,
 );
}
```

Comment: correct property useWideViewPort)

Answer (score 0):

your second image is zoom of real image of webview. to zoom webview page you can write following code.

```
routes: {
"/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
url: url,
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Webview"),
),
withJavascript: true,
withLocalStorage: true,
withZoom: true,
)
}
```

Comment: I want to zoom out version like the webview the first image (without pinch out by the user)

Answer (score 0):

I know it late but maybe it useful for otherS. I able to achieve it by making the withWideViewPort and withOverviewMode true as below

```
WebviewScaffold(
userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) ' + 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94Mobile Safari/537.36',
      withJavascript: true,
      clearCache: true,
      clearCookies: true,
      withZoom: true,
      scrollBar: true,
      useWideViewPort: true,
      url: widget.data.url,
      withOverviewMode: true,`
)
```